# SharePoint Online Search for phone number

Tags: search, office365, sharepoint-online

We have users phone numbers updated in AD and is synced with Office 365 SharePoint Online. Now the users phone numbers have space in between for example: 123 456789.
While searching for the phone number on enterprise search without the space, does not display any result. Like 123456789.
Can anyone suggest any query rule that can be added to make this work.